# Strcmp doesn't work on same strings with same length

Tags: c, fgets, strcmp

So, I have this code, where password is a string obtained by breaking into tokens a bigger string, and  pass obtained from a text file. I even used strcspn so i can remove '\n' from pass.

```
    if (ok == 1){

        char buffer[20];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s.txt", username);

        chdir("./passwords") ;

        FILE *userf;
        userf = fopen(buffer,"r");
        if(userf == NULL){
            perror("Eroare la fopen");
            exit(1);
        } else
            printf("Am deschis fisierul cu parola\n");

        char pass[20];

        if(fgets(pass, sizeof(pass), userf) == NULL){

            perror("Eroare la fgets");
            exit(1);
        } 
        pass [ strcspn(pass, "\r\n") ] = '\0'; 
        printf("%s\n%s\n",password, pass);
        printf("%i %i\n",strlen(password), strlen(pass));

        if(strcmp(password, pass) == 0){
            printf("Connected");
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the terminal it prints out the same string with the same length but strcmp for some reason doesn't return 0.I'm really confused.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? What are the relevant contents of the file (if it's being read correctly, just omit it and hardcode the contents)? I'd like to be able to run this and see the issue. Also, best to show output as text rather than a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Are you shure that pass readed from file contains '\r' or '\n' at the end? If not, and the pass length is 20, you will write the trailing '\0' over the buffer boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a `\n` to the last `printf` you'll see it works fine.

Your program is just exiting before it's flushed the stdout buffer.

Answer (score 2):

How do you know it's not comparing correctly?  If it's by the printed statement you appear to have forgotten the newline character which means it probably won't be flushed to the screen without another print.